# c# regex: getting number from bracket

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I wrote regex for separating some text. I would also like to be able to get value from this bracket ' [] '. This is what I have so far:

```
Regex(@"^(?:(?<C0>Message) from (?<C1>\S+) (?<C2>\S+) to (?<C3>\S+) (?<C4>\S+) (?<C5>.+))$");
```

This is example of my text:

```
Message from device type[3] to receiver type[45] done;
```

I want to be able to separate word type and numer 3 and 45. Now I only get type[3] and type[45] together.

Comment: have you considered just using IndexOf("[") to find the brackets? Is regex the easiest solution?

Comment: I want to stay with regex, because I must also separate rest of the text, so I just need to add this part concerning brackets. I don't want to change everything now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Regex reg = new Regex(@"^(?:(?<C0>Message) from (?<C1>\S+) (?<C2>\S+\[(?<N1>\d+)\]) to (?<C3>\S+) (?<C4>\S+\[(?<N2>\d+)\]) (?<C5>.+))$");
 Match m = reg.Match("Message from device type[3] to receiver type[45] done");

 var n1 = m.Groups["N1"].Value;//3
 var n2 = m.Groups["N2"].Value;//45
```

You can also get `n1`, `n2` from `type[...]`:

```
Regex reg2 = new Regex(@"\S+\[(\d+)\]");          
var n1 = reg2.Match(m.Groups["C2"].Value).Groups[0].Value;
var n2 = reg2.Match(m.Groups["C4"].Value).Groups[0].Value;

//or don't use Regex once you get `type[...]`
var s = m.Groups["C2"].Value.Split(new string[]{"[","]"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var t = s[0];//type
var n = s[1];//3
```

If using `Regex` to get only `type` and `n` in `type[n]`:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^(?:(?<C0>Message) from (?<C1>\S+) (?<T1>\S+)\[(?<N1>\d+)\] to (?<C3>\S+) (?<T2>\S+)\[(?<N2>\d+)\] (?<C5>.+))$");

var t1 = m.Groups["T1"].Value;//type
var n1 = m.Groups["N1"].Value;//3
var t2 = m.Groups["T2"].Value;//type
var n2 = m.Groups["N2"].Value;//45
```

Comment: Great @King King your answer is as always amazing. Thank you!

Comment: I will have one more question. I did it in this way 
Regex(@"^(?:(?<C0>Command) (?:answer|sent) from (?<C1>\S+) (?<C2>\S+\[(?<N1>\d+)\]) to (?<C3>\S+) (?<C4>\S+\[(?<N2>\d+)\]) (?<C5>.+))$");
But I get in C2 "type[3]" and later in N1 I get only "3". What can I do to receive in C2 only word "type"?

Comment: @user2592968 do you want to get the whole `type[3]` or just `type` and `3`?

Comment: I want to get type and 3.

Answer (score 1):

If this format is fix, just add more named groups at the right places

```
Regex(@"^(?:(?<C0>Message) from (?<C1>\S+) (?<C2>\S+)\[(?<C2n>\d+)\] to (?<C3>\S+) (?<C4>\S+)\[(?<C4n>\d+)\] (?<C5>.+))$");
```

You can then get the numbers

```
match.Groups["C2n"].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's what you need : let me know

```
 MatchCollection names = Regex.Matches("Message from device type[3] to receiver type[45] done;", @"Message from device type\[(3)\] to receiver type\[(45)\] done;");

  names[0].Groups[1].Value
  names[0].Groups[2].Value
```

Comment: It is not working. I do it this way (?<C2>\[<C6>]\S+). Maybe it is bad approach?

Comment: it would be a lot easier if you specify the set of rules youre looking for .(it's hard to guess you know...)